# regex just works on explicit given unicode string not on a unicode field of model

Tags: python, django

I have a custom template tag to replace space,tab,newline,!,@,#,$,%,&,(,),., with dash:

```
re.sub('[,@#$%&_.?!\t\n ]+', '-', value)
```

this works fine when I give `value parameter explicitly` :

```
re.sub('[,@#$%&_.?!\t\n ]+', '-', 'نمونه کد')
```

or:

```
value='نمونه کد'
re.sub('[,@#$%&_.?!\t\n ]+', '-', value)
```

but in template when I wanna use this tag on a `subject` field of a list of objects it doesn't work correctely and just replaces spaces with dash:

```
{% for n in news %}
   <a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.getNews n.subject|custom_unicode_slugify,n.pk %}" >{{n.description|safe|truncatewords_html:15}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

this is my custome template tag:

```
def custom_unicode_slugify(value):
    return re.sub('[,@#$%&_.?!\t\n ]+', '-', value)

register.filter('custom_unicode_slugify', custom_unicode_slugify)
```

I tryed to use this tag without `n|custom_unicode_slugify` instead of `n.subject|custom_unicode_slugify`, because my model `__unicode__()` method returns `subject field`,but I get this error:

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this solution:
when using template tags `unicode method` wont run immediately,so I definded `unicode subject` besides `__unicode__` in `models.py`:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.subject
def unicode_subject(self):
    return unicode(self.subject)
```

in template:

```
<a href="{% url CompanyHub.views.DocDetails doc.unicode_subject|custom_unicode_slugify,doc.pk %}">{{doc.content}}</a>
```